Where can I find less common vocabulary?
I am preparing for the IELTS test. In the criteria, there is a requirement that a candidate should be skillful in the use of less common vocabulary to get band 8. So I wonder how I know whether words are or are not less common and where I can find them (websites or online forums).

Unfortunately requests for resources are off-topic. And there are 2 different questions here: how to tell how common words are, and where to find less common words (examples? lists? detailed information?). Several websites do "word of the day" features.

Cambridge Dictionary will sometimes list words according to their difficulty such as meanwhile which is considered level B1, nevertheless is classified B2 (6.5 IELTS), and eradicate is C2 (IELTS 9)

Try this site https://engxam.com/handbook/how-to-practice-improve-vocabulary-tips-list-pdf-c1-advanced-cae/#c1-advanced-cae-vocabulary-list and here https://elt.oup.com/elt/students/navigate/downloads/navigate-c1-wordlist-a-z.pdf?cc=us&selLanguage=en&srsltid=AfmBOooFvcY0SZC0sD8gfR2WHCrpKomUx-JpBZKp522OwGXV-uTQ5Mnz

There are also IELTS training books that focus specifically on Advanced Vocabulary. Buy a second-hand book or look for a pdf version online, it's quite challenging to go through but it will provide context and not merely a list of words.

Please note that in general, with count nouns, you need a determiner: a or the. Or a plural. Count nouns that are not abstract nouns like poverty or wealth. Please see my edit to your question.

Awesome question but ELU is not the place for learning tips. Ask over at [languagelearning.SE] or [ELL.SE].

Google search: “IELTS advanced vocabulary” and C1 wordlist without the speech-marks.
Try out this website called LanGeek
There are 67 categories listed in their C1 wordlist; inexplicably not in alphabetical order. In Money and Finance (#60) the word broke is defined:

broke adjective
having little or no financial resources
Synonym: bust, skint, stone-broke and stony-broke

However, it doesn't tell the student that broke and its synonym are all slang expressions.
In Education (#21) for the verb expel it says

to expel
to force someone to leave a place, organization, etc.
synonym: kick out, throw out
Example
(4) The school decided to expel the student for repeated violations of the code of conduct.

Nothing is mentioned about register. The student should know that expel is formal while throw out and kick out are slang and consequently inappropriate for a formal essay but perfectly acceptable in speech and in an email to a friend.
The "review" section is free but if you want to use the flashcards, test your  spelling, and do the quiz you have to download the app.
